# "insert a smart card" window pops up when install Excel AddIn

Tags: excel, vba, installation, add-in

My Excel AddIn is written in C#, it uses Excel DNA, AddIn Express RTD, NetOffice 
Installer is created with Advanced Installer, plus VBA 
the VBA code is in install.xls

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim quit As Integer
    Dim added As Boolean
    Add_Addin

    If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
        Application.quit
    Else
        Me.Close
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Add_Addin()
    On Error GoTo ERR_

    Dim addinFile As String
    addinFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "MyAddIn.xll"

    If Len(addinFile) > 0 Then
            Dim LEA As AddIn
            Set LEA = Application.AddIns.Add(addinFile)
            If (Not LEA Is Nothing) Then
                LEA.Installed = True
            Else
                MsgBox "Failed to add XLL"
            End If
    Else
        MsgBox "XLL file not found"
    End If

    Exit Sub

ERR_:
    MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Everything works fine.  and I did not change installer 
Now when one user installs new version of my addin, 
when install.xls is run in Excel,  a window pops up saying "insert smart card"

I think and think and figure out the only thing changed (compared with previous version) is digital sigature of the install.xls  b/c the previous signature file expired recently
I signed install.xls with the new certificate

Now the strange window pops up during install.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You've provided absolutely no information we could possibly use to try and answer this question (no information about the add-in, what it's supposed to do, etc.). Voting to close as not a real question (I think I accidentally clicked "off-topic" though).

Comment: Possibly related: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-do-i-disable-the-insert-smart-card-dialog-that/d0800e92-ed5e-4b6f-b811-1f0e1d38572c

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try following the instructions on the link below for adding a trusted location.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-remove-or-modify-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010354311.aspx#BM1

This is a fix I am pursuing for a similar issue.